# Listar ficheiros da memoria interna na ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Pretendo criar uma *app* que ao clicar na opção "Listas" crie uma lista usando `ListView` com base nos ficheiros encontrados numa determinada pasta(caminho) da memoria interna.

Comment: Olá Ekson, seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Para ter maiores chances de obter uma resposta que solucione seu problema, tente esclarecer melhor a pergunta, descrevendo quais as dificuldades que você encontrou para criar essa lista, e outros detalhes que possam ser importantes entender o que você precisa. Dar uma olhada neste tópico  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta da Central de Ajuda também pode ajudar na formatação de sua pergunta, aumentando ainda mais as chances de alguém com conhecimento técnico (e tem bastante por aqui) te auxiliar.

Answer (score 1):

Pensando um pouco é possível fazer várias listagens internas e externas do dispositivo em uma aplicação usando o [*Environment*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) e [*Context*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

- [`Environment.getRootDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getRootDirectory()): Retorna o diretório raiz do sistema Android.
- [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()): Retornar o diretório principal compartilhada/externa de armazenamento.
- [`Environment.getDataDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory()): Retornar o diretório de dados do usuário.
- [`Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDownloadCacheDirectory()): Retornar o diretório de conteúdo download/cache.
- [`getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()): retorna um caminho que está vinculado ao seu pacote e o contexto é necessário para acessar o nome do pacote.

Primeiramente, como exemplo, é necessário conceder permissão de leitura seus diretórios no `manifest.xml` caso queira fazer uma listagem de arquivos externos usando `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Se por uma acaso usar o `getRootDirectory()` não é necessário esta permissão. E se estiver utilizando **Android API 6.0+**, você terá que ler um pouco mais sobre *[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)*.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Na sua `main.xml`, irá inserir seu `ListView` para que sejam listados todos os ficheiros:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

E finalmente na sua classe `Main` é vai fazer desta forma:

```
    ListView listView ;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    String path = Environment.getRootDirectory().toString();
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        list.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Caso queira listar outros diretórios em uma pasta específica, basta você colocar o nome da pasta no seu *path*:

```
String path = Environment.getRootDirectory().toString()+"/"+diretorioEspecifico;
```

Comment: O AP fala em *"Listar ficheiros da memoria **interna** na ListView*".

Comment: @ramaral eu melhorei a resposta, incluindo ficheiros de memória interna. Obrigado.